# Computer want to install Ubuntu when I restart after I completed installation

Tags: usb-installation

It is very strange,

I just installed Ubuntu 16 on my computer, and at the end of the installation, the system says that I need to restart my computer. When I do it, I get back to the black screen that asks me if I want to try Ubuntu or if I want to install it. I'm stuck in an infinite loop.

However the first time I did the installation, I was able to do the crypted one, protected by password. Now I can't. Also, sometimes the system says that some files already exists, which certainly come from the first installation, and that it may cause issues.

Comment: When installing, are you trying to install to a specific directory or are you performing a clean installation that wipes the whole machine?

Comment: Did you remove the USB drive? Are you installing the permanent OS to USB or from USB to a hard-drive?

Comment: One that wipes out everything, and it did, I had windows in the first place and now it says there is no OS detected

Comment: I followed exactly this tutorial https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0

Comment: When removing the USB I get blue screen

Comment: WOOOOOW no it worked I think ! WOWOWOW SUCH WOW

Comment: It specifically tells you when to remove the USB drive: After the installation process have finished and before it reboots. You actively have to press Enter when that line asking you to remove the installation medium is visible on the screen.

Comment: Didn't get that line on my screen, maybe the french version is not as complete as the english one ! Anyway much thanks guys it is working now